# Which form of adjective should be used?

Tags: adjectives, comparative-constructions, superlatives

In the following sentence which form of the adjective should be used?

> There were three four rooms in the hotel, **the smallest/the smaller** of which served as the gym.

I think it should be **the smallest** because the comparison is being made between more than two things.

Comment: What does "three four rooms" mean?

Answer (score 1):

> There were three [to] four rooms in the hotel, the smallest/the smaller of which served as the gym.

To make sense of the sentence, I have added a 'to'.  With that, 'smallest' is right; the comparison is being made among more than two things.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence, as it stands, does not read well. I think this should be either:

> There were three to four rooms in the hotel...  *(really small hotel though!)*

or

> There were three four-room suites in the hotel...

But to answer your question, I suppose this is what you are looking for:

> There were three [to] four rooms in the hotel, **the smallest** of which served as the gym.

[Here](https://www.usinggrammar.com/english-grammar/adjectives-comparison-er-est.php#rules) for instance you can find a summary of comparative and superlative adjectives.